# Permalink-fu - Display URL differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permalinks

I'm using Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 and permalink-fu plugin. I would like to know how to generate permalinks like this: `/posts/44444/this-is-the-title` instead of `/posts/44444-this-is-the-title`

I've tried modifying my `Post` model as follows:

```
  has_permalink :title, :update => true

  def to_param
    "#{permalink}"
  end
```

And my routes file as follows:

```
map.show "/posts/:id/:permalink", :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show'
```

Then, if I manually type the url with that format, it will work, but if I make a link out of a post in my view as follows, it wont generate the link formatted that way:

```
<%= link_to p.title, p %>
```

Where `p` represents a post.

How can I do so when I call a post like that, I get a permalink formatted as `/posts/:id/:permalink` instead of `/posts/:id-:permalink`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

on model:

```
def to_params
  [self.id, self.permalink]
end
```

on views:

```
<%= link_to p.title, show_path(p) %>
```